# How to know information about the clicked bar in highchart column r shiny plot

Tags: javascript, jquery, r, highcharts, shiny

I want to detect some information when the user clicks in a bar of a column highchart plot. I need to know the name and category of the clicked bar, if the name was chosen in the legend or if the background was clicked. The name part is ok, but I cannot discover which is the JS code I have to write to know this type of information.

Many thanks

```
library("shiny")
library("highcharter")

ui <- shinyUI(
  fluidPage(
    column(width = 8, highchartOutput("hcontainer", height = "500px")),
    column(width = 4, textOutput("text"))
  )
)

server <- function(input, output) {      

  a <- data.frame(b = LETTERS[1:10], c = 11:20, d = 21:30, e = 31:40)

  output$hcontainer <- renderHighchart({      

    myClickFunc <- JS("function(event) {Shiny.onInputChange('hcClicked', this.name);}")

    highchart() %>% 
      hc_xAxis(categories = a$b) %>% 
      hc_add_serie(name = "c", data = a$c) %>%
      hc_add_serie(name = "d", data = a$d) %>% 
      hc_add_serie(name = "e", data = a$e) %>%
      hc_plotOptions(series = list(stacking = FALSE, events = list(click = myClickFunc))) %>%
      hc_chart(type = "column")

  })      

  output$text <- renderText({
    input$hcClicked        
  })
}
```

**New questions**
When I click to disable and immediately after to enable a column, I cannot detect the 2nd event. 
How can I detect if a column or the legend was disabled and enabled (or vice versa), without any other different event in the middle?

Other question is: it is possible to detect a click on the plot background?

Thanks

Answer (score 21, accepted):

I'll probably go more into detail this time about what you can do and what possibilities you have:

A `highchart` event function always has the form `JS("function(event) { ... }")`. The `JS` stands for JavaScript and prevents R from interpreting the code inside. Luckily, JavaScript looks a lot like R, which will make it easier to write statements even if you don't know any JavaScript.

The function inside always has to have an `event` parameter. From the `highcharts` documentation, this event has several properties, most important of all, `point`. Properties in JavaScript can be accessed by a dot `.`, just like you would use a `$` in R. So `event.point` will be the point you clicked on.

Now, this point also has a lot of properties, of which most are not very useful. But possible values you might want to use are `category`, `color`, `x` and `y` for respective axis values. So if you'd like to know the y value of the clicked point, `event.point.y` is the command. Another example: in your case, `event.point.x` would yield the `x` value, which in the case of a bar chart is not the `category`, but the index of the `category` (counting starts at 0 here). In the previous example (your code snippet), I also used the object `this`. `this` stands for the `series` that has been clicked. This is just a shortcut, because you could also get the series via `event.point.series`. And the series itself has a lot of properties, like i.e. the `name`.

Note concerning JavaScript: Lists (arrays) in JavaScript are created with the `[ ... ]` brackets. I used this in the code below to send multiple values in one command.

That is the first part. Now, you want to communicate the selection to your shiny app. Shiny has inbuilt information channels for this purpose. One is the JavaScript function `Shiny.onInputChange`. This function has two arguements, the second one is the value you want to send. The first one is the name, under which you want to access the value later on. So the usage is always `Shiny.onInputChange('myVar', value)`. Now this value gets sent to your server and is accessible under `input$myVar`. There, you have the same rules as for any other input. You can put `input$myVar` into reactive environments and they will react, whenever something new is sent to `input$myVar`.

Concerning your direct request: To know what category the clicked value belongs to, can be achieved by changing the initial click function just a bit. (I renamed the functions to suit their functionality.) The explanation above should make it understandable. The second feature, with the legend click, uses another event "slot" that is built into `highcharts`. The `legendItemClick` works just like the normal `click`, but only listens to legend clicks. There are some more event handlers that can be assigned, i.e. `mouseOver` if you need hover events.

Okay, now here is a sample code to give a working example for what I wrote above:

Best regards

```
library("shiny")
library("highcharter")

ui <- shinyUI(
  fluidPage(
    column(width = 8, highchartOutput("hcontainer", height = "500px")),
    column(width = 4, textOutput("text"))
  )
)

server <- function(input, output) {      

  a <- data.frame(b = LETTERS[1:10], c = 11:20, d = 21:30, e = 31:40)

  output$hcontainer <- renderHighchart({      

    canvasClickFunction <- JS("function(event) {Shiny.onInputChange('canvasClicked', [this.name, event.point.category]);}")
    legendClickFunction <- JS("function(event) {Shiny.onInputChange('legendClicked', this.name);}")

    highchart() %>% 
      hc_xAxis(categories = a$b) %>% 
      hc_add_series(name = "c", data = a$c) %>%
      hc_add_series(name = "d", data = a$d) %>% 
      hc_add_series(name = "e", data = a$e) %>%
      hc_plotOptions(series = list(stacking = FALSE, events = list(click = canvasClickFunction, legendItemClick = legendClickFunction))) %>%
      hc_chart(type = "column")

  })      

  makeReactiveBinding("outputText")

  observeEvent(input$canvasClicked, {
    outputText <<- paste0("You clicked on series ", input$canvasClicked[1], " and the bar you clicked was from category ", input$canvasClicked[2], ".") 
  })

  observeEvent(input$legendClicked, {
    outputText <<- paste0("You clicked into the legend and selected series ", input$legendClicked, ".")
  })

  output$text <- renderText({
    outputText      
  })
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Comment: Very goooood answer!

Comment: Hi there, very similar but goes one level deeper with drilldown. Any help you can provide? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55148512/r-highcharter-dynamic-multi-level-drilldown-in-shiny

Comment: I would like to implement something like this for a highcharter map. How can I access the name of the polygons of the rendered map? I'm looking to adapt this specific line of code on your answer `{Shiny.onInputChange('canvasClicked', [this.name, event.point.category]);}`. By the way, awesome answer and explanation!

Comment: Can you post a question with a situation that helps reproduce the situation you're talking about? Those solutions tend to be very situational.