# R Highcharter: Highlight/unhighlight a bar in a bar chart by clicking

Tags: highcharts, r-highcharter

Is it possible to highlight a clicked bar in a highcharter bar chart?  The code below captures the click event on a bar (code is sourced from [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37208989/how-to-know-information-about-the-clicked-bar-in-highchart-column-r-shiny-plot) to this question), the question is to then use this click information to highlight the clicked bar, and then unhighlight when the bar is clicked again or if another bar is clicked.

One way to highlight is to use a plotband (see [here](http://jkunst.com/highcharter/highcharts-api.html)) however I'm flexible as long as the user can see their selection clearly.

```
library("shiny")
library("highcharter")

ui <- shinyUI(
  fluidPage(
    column(width = 8, highchartOutput("hcontainer", height = "500px")),
    column(width = 4, textOutput("text"))
  )
)

server <- function(input, output) {      

  a <- data.frame(b = LETTERS[1:10], c = 11:20, d = 21:30, e = 31:40)

  output$hcontainer <- renderHighchart({      

    canvasClickFunction <- JS("function(event) {Shiny.onInputChange('canvasClicked', [this.name, event.point.category]);}")
    legendClickFunction <- JS("function(event) {Shiny.onInputChange('legendClicked', this.name);}")

    highchart() %>% 
      hc_xAxis(categories = a$b) %>% 
      hc_add_series(name = "c", data = a$c) %>%
      hc_add_series(name = "d", data = a$d) %>% 
      hc_add_series(name = "e", data = a$e) %>%
      hc_plotOptions(series = list(stacking = FALSE, events = list(click = canvasClickFunction, legendItemClick = legendClickFunction))) %>%
      hc_chart(type = "column")

  })      

  makeReactiveBinding("outputText")

  observeEvent(input$canvasClicked, {
    outputText <<- paste0("You clicked on series ", input$canvasClicked[1], " and the bar you clicked was from category ", input$canvasClicked[2], ".") 
  })

  observeEvent(input$legendClicked, {
    outputText <<- paste0("You clicked into the legend and selected series ", input$legendClicked, ".")
  })

  output$text <- renderText({
    outputText      
  })
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are looking for a **plotOptions.column.allowPointSelect** property:
[API - allowPointSelect](https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/series.column.allowPointSelect)

Just update line 25 in your code:

```
hc_plotOptions(series = list(stacking = FALSE, allowPointSelect = TRUE, events = list(click = canvasClickFunction, legendItemClick = legendClickFunction))) %>%
```

To select more than 1 point, hold **ctrl** button pressed.

Comment: This works a treat.  Is there also a way to have an equivalent `allowCategorySelect` when the columns are stacked so it could selected all the points in a stacked column?

Comment: It can be easily done with pure JS using point.select() method: https://api.highcharts.com/class-reference/Highcharts.Point#select (looping through all points in the stack) but I am a beginner with R and I am not sure how to implement this in R. I can try tommorow

Comment: I'm guessing it can be done by using the id of the highchart to manipulate it after creation, however I haven't found any examples of this for highcharts in R.

Comment: I've now asked this question here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54301374/r-highcharter-manipulate-a-highchart-after-creation

Comment: Done ;) easier than I thought :D You will find the answer in the new topic you have created (link above).