# Choosing R Highcharter colours for each drilldown level graph in Rshiny

Tags: r, shiny, r-highcharter, drilldown

I am creating a drill down in Rshiny similar to the solution in this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55168485/r-highcharter-dynamic-drilldown-in-shiny-on-the-fly) but I have 6 drill-down levels whereas the original question has 3 levels. Is there a way to specify the colours for each drill-down level?  E.g. using the referenced question, I would be able to specify the colours for level 1 city, farm and ocean, level 2 bus and car, level 3 carl and newt etc (as seen in screenshots below). Is this possible?

Drilldown level 1
[image]

Select level 1 "City" resulting in level 2 bus and car
[image]

Select level 2 "Bus" resulting in Carl and Newt etc.
[image]

What I've tried:

```
......
highchart() %>%
      hc_xAxis(type = "category") %>%
      hc_add_series(tibbled, "column", hcaes(x = name, y = y), color = "#E4551F", "#4572A7", 
"#AA4643", "#89A54E", "#80699B", "#3D96AE") %>%
      hc_plotOptions(column = list(stacking = "normal", events = list(click = pointClickFunction)))
```

This didn't work, it just used the first hex code . Surely there has to be a way to say "for category city use colour "#4572A7" etc" ??
Please help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a few different ways you could do this. You didn't provide a reproducible question, so I've used the data `gapminder`.

The highest level is the average life expectancy by continent. The second level is the average by country. The third level is the life expectancy by country by year.

I used the `highcharter` function `colorize` to create color vectors. This is how I put it together:

The data

```
library(tidyverse)
library(highcharter)
data(gapminder, package = "gapminder")

avLE = gapminder %>% 
  group_by(continent) %>% 
  mutate(aLE = mean(lifeExp)) %>% # average by continent
  ungroup() %>% group_by(country) %>% 
  mutate(caLE = mean(lifeExp)) %>% # average by year
  ungroup() %>% arrange(desc(aLE)) %>% # order by life expectancy for continents
  mutate_if(is.numeric, round, 2)  # round to 2 decimals
summary(avLE) # check it; makes sense

gapCol = avLE %>%  # set the continets in the validated avLE as ordered
  group_by(continent) %>% 
  mutate(color = colorize(continent),
         continent = ordered(continent, 
                             levels = unique(avLE$continent)))
summary(gapCol) # check it; makes sense
```

The drill downs

```
# make the deepest level dropdown
gapDD2 = avLE %>% 
  arrange(year) %>%  
  group_nest(continent, country, caLE) %>% # keep these variables!
  mutate(id = country,
         type = "column", 
         data = map(data, mutate, name = year, y = lifeExp,
                    color = colorize(year)), # set the color (easier with #)
         data = map(data, list_parse))

gapDD1 = avLE %>% 
  arrange(country) %>%  # arrange by country, set as ordered, then find colors
  mutate(country = ordered(country, levels = unique(country))) %>%
  mutate(color = ordered(colorize(country),     # colors/countries align
                         levels = unique(colorize(country)))) %>% 
  group_nest(continent) %>% 
  mutate(id = continent,
         type = "column", 
         data = map(data, mutate, name = country, y = caLE, 
                    color = color,  # set the color (a few more steps than with #s)
                    drilldown = country),
         data = map(data, list_parse))
```

The chart

```
# take a look:
hchart(gapCol, "column", name = "Continental Averages",
       hcaes(x = continent, color = continent, y = aLE, 
             name = "continent", drilldown = "continent")) %>% 
  hc_drilldown(allowPointsDrillDown = T,
               series = c(list_parse(gapDD1), list_parse(gapDD2)))
```

[image]

[image]

[image]

---

---

#### With Shiny

I've provided a really simple example of how to render this plot within a Shiny application. In this example, all of the code, except the call `hchart`, is called before the `ui` is set.

```
ui <- fluidPage(
  fluidRow(highchartOutput("myHC"))
)
server <- function(input, output, session){
  output$myHC <- renderHighchart({
    hchart(gapCol, "column", name = "Continental Averages",
           hcaes(x = continent, color = continent, y = aLE, 
                 name = "continent", drilldown = "continent")) %>% 
      hc_drilldown(allowPointsDrillDown = T,
                   series = c(list_parse(gapDD1), list_parse(gapDD2))) 
  })
}
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Let me know if you have any questions.

Comment: Thank you for your response. I apologise if my question was unclear, but the question I referenced was run in R shiny, how can I modify your code to run in R shiny?

Comment: Sorry about that! I don't know if I missed it or not, but I can help. Unfortunately, I just saw this. Please give me a bit to get the information into my answer for you. (I'm currently burning the midnight oil for a work project due yesterday!)

Comment: @Thandi, answer updated with a really basic Shiny App. Let me know if you have any questions.